# What do I need out of ASP.NET and IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I'm brand new to C#/.NET

1. Why does ASP.NET have so many different choices of projcets? (Web Application, Web API, Web Site, MVC ect). I just want to listen on a tcp port, and a way to send a response. If there are libraries to help me do routine stuff like constructing the HTTP request, parsing the header, ect - then cool. But I don't want a super opinionated framework that tries to do everything under the sun.
2. Why do I need IIS at all?

Comment: 1. Because VS still doesn't read minds and doesn't know what your intentions are. 2. From what you say you don't seem to need IIS, and actually no ASP neither...

Comment: I don't use VS. OK good, don't need IIS then. Thanks

Comment: You don't use VS ? First mistake if you ask me... You probably won't find a better IDE for .NET, at least on windows...

Comment: I use it for debugging - best debugger I've used across any platform (though I've only used it to debug C/C++ at this point). I just don't like developing in an IDE - personal choice

Comment: Well, your choice indeed, but you're most probably being less productive than if you were using one... I really find it very strange but hey, anyone is strange to someone else :-)

Comment: Read this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5

Comment: I suggest learning the ASP.NET platform and the .NET Framework

Comment: @MikeGoodwin Good find! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your points in reverse order, first - why do I need IIS?

The answer is, maybe you don't. If you are doing a simple listener that won't be exposed to the public internet, then you don't need it.

If you are doing a web application that needs to scale, be robust and easy to manage then it can help you with:

- Logging
- Operating in a multi-server environment for scale/high availability
- Handling multiple requests in an isolated way
- Serving multiple applications from the same host with sandboxing to ensure each application has guaranteed resources (memory, CPU)
- Application lifecycle management
- IP address restrictions
- support for FTP, CGI, WebDAV
- URL rewriting
- Response header manipulation
- Failed request tracing
- Protection against some DoS exploits like slow HTTP attacks
- Etc.

In short, it is an industrial strength, real world web server that will keep your application up reliably in a hostile world and scale as your application grows. it is certainly overkill for some cases if you don't need this kind of scale/high availability/management capability. In those cases you have the option to self host ASP.Net in a Windows Service or even a console app. This might sound complicated, but it has been made pretty simple by OWIN - Open Web Interface for .Net. This is an abstraction of the interface used by Asp.Net to communicate with its hosting server.

There is a very good tutorial on how to self host web API in a console app here

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

It does exactly what you ask for in your comment:

- You create a console app project
- You add references to the right assemblies (the tutorial uses NuGet to download the assembly packages)
- You code up your web operation logic
- You compile
- You run the resulting exe
- That's it!

On your second point about ASP.Net - it is a framework that has gone through a lot of evolution trying to keep up with very rapid changes in the web development world. This meant it got a bit bloated and lost some of its coherence, but recently the developers have been focussed on making it more lightweight, more modular and simpler. Scott Guthrie summarises it in his blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for - thank you Mike. As a very quick follow-up, do you know what self-hosting Scott Guthrie talks about? I'm new to the web-world, but naively just want to compile my code, link-in whatever .NET libs I need, and execute the CIL "exe" in it's own process.

Comment: @kat: I added some extra info on self hosting

Comment: Sorry, it took me awhile to get back to you - weekends :). This is **exactly** what I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does ASP.NET have so many different choices of projcets? (Web Application, Web API, Web Site, MVC ect). I just want to listen on a tcp port, and a way to send a response. etc...

Because each project has its own purpose.
If you want to *just* listen on a TCP port then you could go learn Microsoft's **Katana OWIN** (but I highly doubt if this is what you want).
[Katana OWIN](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana)

Briefly going through each projects purpose:

1. **"Web Application"** actually opens up another window and lets you choose from the following:
2. **Web API** is for exposing RESTful services or JSON data.
3. **Web Forms** is for making web pages that use Web Form components.
   (A bit like Windows Forms, but Web)
4. **MVC** is for making Model-View-Controller web applications. This is where you build components with a separation of concerns. Model for data. View for what the user sees. Controller for controlling how your page behaves.

> Why do I need IIS at all?

**[IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)** is for serving .NET applications.
Without it, it would be quite hard to serve .NET applications.

Comment: So the projects just impose some architectural/design patterns on me? I still don't see why requests need to hit IIS first. What does IIS do for me that I can't do for myself?

Comment: My answer would be the same as @MikeGoodwin

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with **2** then move on to your first question. IIS will run whatever the .NET web service you need, be it a monstrous WCF service, an ASP.NET application or the most basic http handler.

To my knowledge, ISS is the most straightforward way to use .NET web services. If you are used to PHP, it's basically LAMP or WAMP for .NET, which means it is sort of necessary. There are alternatives, as Mike Goodwin points out, but I have to admit I am not familiar with those third parties. Since replacing a layer for another doesnt mean much, I would stick to the "normal" procedure.

Since you dont want the framework to do a truckload of operations for you, your best bet might be along those lines:

1. Create a basic ASP.NET projet
2. Remove the default ASP.Net page because it seems you dont want it
3. Add a *Generic Handler* to your project. This will result in a myFile.ashx, which handles http requests and let you build any response you want

Of course, if you dont want to bother with IIS configurations, you'll need someone to setup an URL on IIS and map it against your handler repository.

---

**EDIT**: 
"Abstraction layers" would be the very definition of frameworks, for good or ill, so you're stucked with it.

Now, since you have a low level background a not-so-intrusive way to work with the .NET web services would probably be the three steps I suggested earlier. You are still stucked with IIS though, in order handles the communications (i.e. manages sockets/requests). That's the way the framework works.

**STILL, THERE IS HOPE**. If you have complete control over your server (which is *not* my case, some other IT team manages the web servers), you certainly could build a windows service that listens to some socket and work the requests accordingly. It is a most unusal solution if you want to serve web pages, but would work rather well if you only want to push some data through http requests. If you go down this path, I suggest you take a look at the [System.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net(v=vs.110).aspx) namespaces, you'll find some classes like "Socket" there. Combined with a console application or a windows service, you could work something out.

One of my coworkers is former microcontroller designer, I know exactly what kind of feeling you have towards the .NET framework. You'll go through some frustrations at times, but most of the time there are work arrounds. Feel free to request more details if you need some.

Comment: What does IIS do for me though? Why do I need the request to go to IIS first rather than directly to me?

Comment: "ISS is the most straightforward -if not the only- way to use .NET web services"  - no, you can self host ASP.Net in a console app, Windows service etc. A quick Google produced this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Comment: Great, another abstraction layer.

Comment: It goes through IIS(or another third party) first because you are using a framework that relies on IIS or some other service in order to work. In the end, your question seems impossible to answer because you ask about the features of a framework then mention you dont want the framework to do things you. Anyway I added a small edit, but I have to admit I'm a little confused.

Comment: Regarding your edit: my background is low level, and so I like to have as much control/knowledge of what's going on as possible (albeit, my web programming experience is limited). I'm already nervous about the whole .NET CLR. The only reason for C#/.NET is that it's the only thing my employer will let me program in for this project  :S.They have a full MS stack and limited budget to support other tech.

Comment: Changed my edit, I get the general idea now. I think going further would be beyond the point of your question, but please review this edit and notify me if I left some details uncovered.

Comment: @Kat: The .Net CLR approach is fundamentally about reliability. To a small extent it sacrifices raw speed for scalability and protection from buffer overruns and other native code issues.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin I understand that. It's just weird for me not to be able to disassemble my code and know what's going on - though ildasm helps.